# Python EOFError for 2nd raw_input in Script only on WSL

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, eoferror

I have a basic script that I am running in a WSL Terminal (Ubuntu 18.04) that gets 2 inputs from a user to create an email, essentially it get the message and then the server to use.

It prompts for the message first and allows the user to enter the input, this works fine. After that it then does a regex search for a servername in the message, if its not found it prompts for it, however each time it does it comes up with an EOFError and I can't find why.

```
ServerTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dev/bin/script", line 155, in <module>
create_report()
File "/home/dev/bin/script", line 98, in create_report
servername=get_servername()
File "/home/dev/bin/script", line 10, in get_servername
servername = raw_input("Server")
EOFError
```

Oddly if I run the same script with python2 -i /home/dev/bin/script  it works, but from the WSL terminal it comes up with the EOFError.

Any help would be really appreciated, I am new to this and a bit lost as to whats happening.

This is the 2nd input, the one that produces the EOFError

```
def get_servername():
servername = raw_input("Server")
return servername
```

From an strace I also see this;

```
26004 read(3, "log_info(\"Parsing report for IPs"..., 512) = 512
26004 read(3, " break\nif not servername:\n    lo"..., 512) = 512
26004 write(2, "    ", 4)               = 4
26004 write(2, "servername = raw_input(\"Server N"..., 40) = 40
26004 close(3)                          = 0
26004 write(2, "EOFError", 8)           = 8
26004 write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
26004 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc31ec3ef20}, {sa_handler=0x7fc31f76c130, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc31ec3ef20}, 8) = 0
26004 exit_group(1)                     = ?
26004 +++ exited with 1 +++
```

The script works fine in Interactive mode, and also when run on a Linux machine directly.

I am not sure but I think something from stdin is not being set correctly or similar?

Any help greatly appreciated.